# How to discharge a plastic surface?

Tags: charge

In a plastic sheet surface, how to make the surface charge disappeared ?

Comment: Some more details would be helpful. Is this a one-time thing? Do you need the charge to be permanently gone? Why do you need a lack of surface charge?

Answer (score 1):

One way to discharge a plastic sheet is to spray it with charged particles, for example, from a radioactive source emitting alpha particle as produced by an [alpha ionising brush](http://www.company7.com/staticmaster/products/staticmaster.html) , by using a balanced ion generator or, perhaps the simplest, using an ordinary flame which contains lots of ions.